# Download stickers in real time from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have created a sticker app for WhatsApp in the android studio. Currently, it's working but all the stickers are placed inside the project folder. The problem is if I add more stickers it increases the `apk` size. Now I want to save all the stickers on firebase and let the user download them in real-time. This functionality is already implemented in Stickify Store app, which is available on play store

Answer (score 0):

I would actually go with the Dynamic module delivery. You can separate the your stickers in different modules and download them when the user needs them on run time.
You can read more here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery

Comment: Well i understand but i want how to code it, any documentation or something?

Comment: Now I am not sure since I had to read many examples to make it work. I do remember reading this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/index.html#6 . For me it was hard to understand the concept at first but when you get it to work it is really simple.